# XP machine rebooting on start-up screen

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot

I have been having a reoccurring problem with an XP machine of mine in which I have encountered many errors. I have managed to resolve these but now I am stuck with my XP machine rebooting on the windows start-up screen, although I have had this problem in the past when trying to boot from a USB (as I needed to put the HDD inside of another machine in order to replace the operating system). Also the machine will not boot in any mode.

The operating system runs fine on another machines but reboots constantly on the start-up screen and I have tried removing hardware to counteract this error but it still persists.

Comment: So you are currently booting off of USB? What this installed via another machine that maybe is using a different CPU architecture? XP isn't always happy switching architectures. Does it BSOD, or just restart? And at what point exactly does it restart?

Comment: I'm booting from Hard-drive now, I installed XP on another machine and placed the hdd back in to its original case. And it just restarts, no BSOD, and at the point where the XP start up screen commences, no bars appear the machine just reboots.

Comment: How different are the CPU architectures and hardware profiles between the two computers?

Comment: I've just noticed that the CPU architectures are different, the XP machine is 32 bit whereas the machine the OS was installed on was 64, apart from that all of the hardware being used is on-board, graphics etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon being installed, Windows will configure itself to boot from the architecture of that specific machine, and expect it to be the same next time it starts.

Trying to boot on a different kind of processor, like the OP states on a comment he's doing, usually causes BSOD's or restarts.